# JSON Decode Base64 DataStream Apache Flink

Tags: apache-flink

need some advice, i have create a flink job using scala to consume message from Kafka.
But the message in commpressed in base64 encoded.
i've try this code

```
    val x_stream: DataStream[ObjectNode] = env
      .addSource(
        new FlinkKafkaConsumer010[ObjectNode](parameters.get("kafka.topic.source"),
          new JsonNodeDeserializationSchema(),
          kfk_props
        ).setStartFromEarliest()
      ).name("Topic Test")).rebalance
```

the code failed direcly becaouse it's not valid Json format.

and then i try to use SimpleStringSchema(), like below code

```
    val x_stream: DataStream[String] = env
      .addSource(
        new FlinkKafkaConsumer010[String](parameters.get("kafka.topic.source"),
          new SimpleStringSchema(),
          kfk_props
        ).setStartFromEarliest()
      ).name("Topic Test")).rebalance
```

the kafka message consumen perfectly, but the output just like below

```
.....
    Br?G"p)0?p?AF??g}?Ly?@?
    ??>??j?)??);?E?]<dâ•š? ?-?@?g?????'2???â•�?â•�o???r?z????Q$????p    Fâ•”?7?yx+_'v?2???K&??O??c??D,c0F2??ny[?=??%?/?M1:???bq?yHt"A??5???
```

How can i decode this data into valid JSON?

best regards,

Answer (score 0):

You should implement the KafkaDeserializationSchema interface to customize the parsing logic.

First, decode base64 and convert it into a byte stream, then generate a string object, and finally parse it into json

Comment: Do you have a little bit sample to decode base64 ?

Comment: Base64.getDecoder().decode(new String(input))

Comment: hi @changli thanks for your reply, but i mean there is some way do decode from DataStream object